# What is the benefit of having RelativeLayout after the introduction of ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I totally understand the advantage of having `ConstraintLayout` when flatenning nested UI's. But with the introduction of `ConstraintLayout` I see people adopting it instead of `RelativeLayout` even for simple layouts with a flat structure.

- Does ConstraintLayout always performs better than RelativeLayout?
  Specifically in the case when a view can be achieved with `single flat 
  structure` with no nested UI?
- If yes, shouldn't `Relative Layout` be deprecated?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that should be a matter of choice and customs. Some UI designers prefer `RelativeLayout` where others prefer `ConstraintLayout`. The `ConstraintLayout` can be used in many cases more than the `RelativeLayout`. And yes it performs better than the `RelativeLayout` but I think for just a single flat structure I can opt for `RelativeLayout` too though due to support tooling provided by the `ConstraintLayout` it makes it a better option if you need that feature.

That's my point of view.

Comment: Nice answer, but I want to mention something.  I totally agree with you about `ConstraintLayout ` speed ***but*** make sure that you are not using nested view groups. Well, if you do use nested view groups your constraintLayout will lose its "magic" and no longer be fast as it could be (think of it like a superhero that needs to keep  a flat view hierarchy  or he will lose power. and losing power = bad guys win, we don't want that )

Comment: That's true yeah. Super sampled comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it performs better, ConstraintLayout has designed with performance optimization in mind. Also, it's very straightforward to use by just drag and drop things.
I really like Constraint layout to develop complex layout faster than any other one, but in my opinion, it's harder to make changes on it when you need, but is just my point of view

Comment: thank you for helping this community with your time and effort, you got my upvote.
I do want to say this as my opinion - I don't believe that is harder to make changes when you need to, In my opinions, you just have to practice and build a lot of layouts and after some time you will manage to change your layout as you want to in only a few minutes.

Comment: Hey Tamir, thank you for your comment!! I found myself sometimes having a hard time changing some really complex layout with a lot of constraints, that why I point it out. Your point is true tho, maybe it's just lack of practice, i'm not an expert on ConstraintLayout yet, so I think this is why is being hard to me lol, thank you for your opinion!!

Comment: So let me tell you this - just text me via [my linkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/tamir-abutbul-10a695178/), I will gladly help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1** - *Does ConstraintLayout always performs better than RelativeLayout*

**A1** - I saw a lot of questions and answers on StackOverflow about that subject and here is what I can say base on those threads and my personal experience with ConstraintLayout :

- In most cases, if you are using  ConstraintLayout properly it will work faster **but** , there is no guaranty that this is what you will get all the time.
- From my personal experience with ConstraintLayout, it is working really fast and in all of my layouts (both simple and complicated in terms of UI) it works faster than RelativeLayout.

---

**Q2** -  *shouldn't Relative Layout be deprecated*

**A2** - Why I believe that Relative Layout should not be deprecated.

- I honestly don't see any valid reason for RelativeLayout to be deprecated, altho I am using ConstaintLayout I first started with RelativeLayout and now I see it as another tool to build my UI.
- If it's not broken don't fix it:

  - Don't forget that there are a lot of developers around the globe, some prefer 
    RelativeLayout and some prefer ConstraintLayout, let's keep it this way is what I believe - don't take the option to choose from the developers, give them the option to choose what to use.
  - ConstraintLayout is not a better solution for building UI as a fact, its just my opinion.

    I really think that its something that depends on the developer and his decisions, therefore - no layout is better than the other and no layout should be deprecated (as long as it works)

---